# Is it possible to inject dependencies into Hazelcast Jet pipeline stages?

Tags: hazelcast-jet

For example, given a simple pipeline such as:

```java
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
p.readFrom(TestSources.items("the", "quick", "brown", "fox"))
 .map(mapFn)
 .writeTo(Sinks.logger());
```

I'd like `mapFn` to be something requiring a non-serialisable dependency to do its work.

I know I can do this:

```java
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
p.readFrom(TestSources.items("the", "quick", "brown", "fox"))
 .mapUsingService(JetSpringServiceFactories.bean("myDependencies"),
         MyDependencies::addDependencies);
 .map(mapFn)
 .writeTo(Sinks.logger());
```

This wraps the strings being read from the source in another object that includes the dependencies, giving `mapFn` access to those dependencies without them needing to be injected into that object itself. That will work, but I want to use my mapping function outside Jet as well as part of a pipeline, and in that case it's a bit weird to have to pass dependencies along with the items being mapped rather than just initialising the mapper with the dependencies it needs. It also forces me to pointlessly create a wrapper object per item in my stream/batch.

The docs say another alternative is to use the `@SpringAware` annotation on `Processor`, but I think that means using the Core API, which the docs says "mostly offers you a lot of ways to make mistakes", so I'd prefer to avoid that.

In vanilla Hazelcast IMDG, anything that is deserialised can use a `ManagedContext` to initialise itself, and this is obviously the case with Jet too, but the functions, filters etc. of the pipeline are wrapped in lots of layers of Jet pipeline stuff and so there seems to be no way to get to them.

Am I missing something or have I listed all the options I have (other than resorting to some "global" `static` dependencies object)?

Answer (score 2):

The way you described is actually quite close to how it should be done. You can simplify it by just doing:

```java
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
p.readFrom(TestSources.items("the", "quick", "brown", "fox"))
 .mapUsingService(bean("myDependencies"), (dep, item) -> mapFn.apply(dep, item));
 .writeTo(Sinks.logger());
```

This avoids creating an intermediate item. As you said already, this requires that the mapping function takes the dependency as a parameter as well.

If you want to avoid that, another option is writing a custom `ServiceFactory` which will do the mapping and also take the dependency. This way, you can rewrite your mapping function as a service and have the dependency injected at the constructor level.

Regarding having a static container I think that would be possible to implement but would require some changes in core. A similar thing was done for `Metrics` class which also works in a static context. There's also this related issue here:

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/issues/954

If you are interested in contributing I can give you some pointers.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. Unfortunately I may have oversimplified my example. While I used `map` in the example, I actually want to do various operations, including `aggregate`. I see there are map/flatMap/filter versions of `usingService`, but I don't think I can aggregate this way can I?

Comment: With aggregation, you can write a custom aggregator that takes the item + dependency as input to the accumulation function. It's probably a bit more complex than it needs to be, but should work. You just need to make sure your accumulator (which holds the aggregation results) is serializable.

Comment: That's the scenario I'm trying to avoid though. I'd like to have a custom aggregator (defined using `AggregateOperation.withCreate` etc) that is serialisable that when deserialised on cluster members can have non-serialisable dependencies injected, which it can then use when aggregating items. As you say, the alternative it to have it do the actual aggregation on item + dependency, but that makes the code very weird when used in a non-Jet context.

Comment: Do you mind creating an issue on the github repo, so we can investigate if it would be possible to do this?

Comment: Sure. https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/issues/2405

Answer (score 1):

If your mapFn is inside a bean then you can just use it as your service:

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
p.readFrom(TestSources.items("the", "quick", "brown", "fox"))
 .mapUsingService(JetSpringServiceFactories.bean(MyService.class), MyService::mapFn);
 .writeTo(Sinks.logger());
```

Full self contained example, where the pipeline calls mapFn on MyService, which uses its dependency for the mapping:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TutorialApplication implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    JetInstance jetInstance;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TutorialApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {

        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
        p.readFrom(TestSources.items("the", "quick", "brown", "fox"))
         .mapUsingService(JetSpringServiceFactories.bean(MyService.class), MyService::mapFn)
         .writeTo(Sinks.logger());

        jetInstance.newJob(p);
    }

    @Component
    public static class MyService {

        @Autowired
        MyDependency foo;

        public String mapFn(String s) {
            return foo.bar(s);
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class MyDependency {

        public String bar(String s) {
            return "mod: " + s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. Bit of a Stack Overflow newbie so not sure how I should do this, but see the clarification I added to Can Gencer's answer. In short, I think I oversimplified my example!